# Connect to VM via RDP with AzureAD credentials

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to RDP into an Azure VM using AzureAD credentials. The account I am using is a guest account in my tenant and the RBAC permissions are configured correctly.
I was following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows to get it configured.

Nevertheless I am running into the issue described in the section "Unauthorized client" in the previously mentioned documentation. Still getting the error message that the password is not correct.

I can connect without any issues using the admin account of the VM but not with AzureAD credentials (neither with user accounts or guest user accounts).

The device (VM) is properly joined to AzureAD.

Any idea?

Comment: Try with these

**1)**   RDP VM using Azure AD credentials, ensure you are using the correct credentials. You may also reset the password and try logging in

**2)** under the System Properties, select **Remote tab**. Under Remote Desktop, select **Allow remote connections to this computer**. Untick Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication. **Click Apply and OK.**

Comment: That does not solve the issue. Is it possible that guest accounts cannot RDP into a VM being hosted on another subscription?

Comment: Just tried to login to the VM with an account out of the same AAD as the subscription. But it does not work either.
How about the username ist it just user@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com?

Comment: Hi @FernSeher ,does the user or guest user have VM contributor role assigned to them ?

Comment: @ShrutiJoshi-MT: Yes, both users have VM contributor permissions assigned.

Comment: RDP using Azure AD credentials, the user must belong to one of the two Azure roles, **Virtual Machine Administrator Login** or **Virtual Machine User Login** . Is user have these roles?

Comment: is the issue resolved?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. But I assume the reason is due to this:
"Remote connection to VMs joined to Azure AD is only allowed from Windows 10 PCs that are either Azure AD registered (starting Windows 10 20H1), Azure AD joined or hybrid Azure AD joined to the same directory as the VM."
My host machine running mstsc.exe is neither AD joined nor registered. Thus it might not work.

Comment: Ya that is the reason ,Please refer this document :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows#log-in-using-azure-ad-credentials-to-a-windows-vm